# Beamer - building footnote example with columns and minipage

Tags: beamer, footnotes, minipage, columns

While trying to construct a `beamer` slide illustrating usage of the `\footnote` command I hit upon the following problems.

When I compile a slide with the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Footnotes}
\begin{columns}[t,onlytextwidth]\footnotesize
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
He was a ruffian\footnote{A thug, hoodlum.} to the bone who hated both Alice and White Hare.
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{semiverbatim}
He was a
ruffian\\footnote\{A thug, hoodlum.\}
to the bone who hated
both Alice and White Hare.
\end{semiverbatim}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

what I receive is the following slide:

[image: output]

So I decided to resort to `minipage` environment to avoid flushing the code beyond the frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Footnotes}
\begin{columns}[t,onlytextwidth]\footnotesize
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
He was a ruffian\footnote{A thug, hoodlum.} to the bone who hated both Alice and White Hare.
\end{minipage}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{semiverbatim}
He was a
ruffian\\footnote\{A thug, hoodlum.\}
to the bone who hated
both Alice and White Hare.
\end{semiverbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Yet in this case, although aligning is OK, the text in the left `minipage` is squeezed in a way which makes it look rather, say, inelegant:

[image: output]

I would like to ask you to help me understand what's going on here and why, and tell me what is best remedy. I know there are beamer packages that are particularly suited for frames like this, but I am curious why these problems arise why I use the tools above.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the desired result here is, however I believe that `\footnote{A thug, hoodlum.}` would be the standard usage (I believe?) in place of `\\footnote\{A thug, hoodlum\}`.

Comment: Yes, \footnote{A thug, hoodlum.} is a standard <code>footnote</code> LaTeX command.

Comment: My apologies, I missed that it was in the semiverbatim environment.  You are correct.

As a quick remedy to the problem (will wait for someone better than I to give reason for the result) one could use `\footnotemark` inside the column, and `\footnotetext[1]{A thug, hoodlum.}` outside of the columns.

Comment: It solves the problem of flushing the inside the right-hand column beyond the frame, but footnote is placed beyond columns, which is not what I try to achieve. I want to place it inside to create a small example of a page with a footnote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give a width of `\textwidth` to the `minipage` so that it occupies the entire column. Please note that the `minipage` is inside a column and `\columnwidth` is `\textwidth` for that `minipage`. I have reduced column width slightly (`0.47\textwidth`) and added a `\hfill` for clarity.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Footnotes}
\begin{columns}[t,onlytextwidth]\footnotesize
\begin{column}{0.47\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
He was a ruffian\footnote{A thug, hoodlum.} to the bone who hated both Alice and White Hare.
\end{minipage}%
\end{column}
\hfill
\begin{column}{0.47\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\begin{semiverbatim}
He was a
ruffian\\footnote{A thug, hoodlum.}
to the bone who hated
both Alice and White Hare.
\end{semiverbatim}
\end{minipage}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do not know why I thought that declaring \begin{minipage}[t][0.5\textpage] sets width of the minipage, not its content...

Answer (score 4):

This is more a suggestion than an answer. As it looks like you are writing a `LaTeX` tutorial I'd suggest some package which can help you. You are writing a latex code within a `verbatim` environment to show which code produces the side result. There are some package which just need that you type the code and produce both code and result. Take a look at [`showexpl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showexpl) or [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).

Last one provides a `tcblisting` environment which with a code like

```
\begin{tcblisting}{title={Footote example}}
He was a ruffian\footnote{A thug, hoodlum.} to the bone who hated both Alice and White Hare.
\end{tcblisting}
```

produces

[image]

And with some options you can obtain a result very similar to your example:
[image]

The complete code for both figures is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[listingsutf8,skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tcbset{listing style={tcblatex,breakindent=0pt}}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Footnotes}

\begin{tcblisting}{title={Footote example}}
He was a ruffian\footnote{A thug, hoodlum.} to the bone who hated both Alice and White Hare.
\end{tcblisting}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Footnotes}

\begin{tcblisting}{enhanced,text side listing,frame hidden,
segmentation hidden,colback=pink,opacityback=0,left=0pt,right=0pt,middle=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt}
He was a ruffian\footnote{A thug, hoodlum.} to the bone who hated both Alice and White Hare. 
\end{tcblisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a hint! I was aware of showexpl but didn't about tcolorbox, which seems very nice.

Comment: Ignasi, is there an easy way to use tcblisting within overlays?

Comment: @MadHatter   If you mean the complete box (code and result), yes. But use environments `\begin{onlyenv}<1-> ... \end{onlyenv}` instead of commands `\only<1->{}`. If you mean applying overlays to code and result I don't think so, but you can ask here. Thomas F. Sturm (`tcolorbox` author) is also member of TeX.SX club.